# Distribute the services across all nodes

Tags: kubernetes-deployment

I have a 2 worker node kube cluster and I have deployments with replica as 2 as seen in deployment shown below

Initially, the deployments were distributed across each node. But one node went down, the other node had 2 pods per deployment.  This is correct and expected. But when the node that was down came up and running. I would like the deployments to be distributed. How can I achieve that.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kub-homenet-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kub-homenet
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kub-homenet
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kub-homenet
          image: naveeenzone/img-kub-homenet:latest
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /app
              name: nfs-vol
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-vol
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kub-starnet-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kub-starnet
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kub-starnet
    spec:
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: node
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
      containers:
        - name: kub-starnet
          image: naveeenzone/img-kub-starnet:latest
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /app
              name: nfs-vol
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-vol
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvc
```

I applied the changes as above, the two pods are running only on one node instead of two.

Nodes information:

```
kubectl get nodes

kubmst01.homenet.n4softsol.ca   Ready    master   162d   v1.18.1
kubwrk01.homenet.n4softsol.ca   Ready    <none>   161d   v1.18.1
kubwrk02.homenet.n4softsol.ca   Ready    <none>   161d   v1.18.1
```

```
 kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide| grep star
default       kub-starnet-deployment-77fd84df46-gwpjf                 1/1     Running   0          38m     10.10.97.177    kubwrk02.homenet.n4softsol.ca   <none>           <none>
default       kub-starnet-deployment-77fd84df46-wtsgf                 1/1     Running   0          38m     10.10.97.178    kubwrk02.homenet.n4softsol.ca   <none>           <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

use topologySpreadConstraints with topologyKey equals node, so pods will be distributed across nodes. maxSkew is used in order to set the maximum number of pods that can be scheduled in one node.

```
spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: node
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
```

Link where you can see how to configure everything:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/